# Scraping data from a website with VBA

Tags: javascript, html, css, vba, web-scraping

I'm new to vba, and html, but I know matlab - but I don't havew matlab on my personal computer so I'm stuck with vba. I'm hoping you can help. I want to scrape some data from a website.. I've found a piece of example code that works for a particular website but not mine. Here is the code I'm trying to get working:

```
    Dim appIE As Object
    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With appIE
    .Navigate "http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.htmlt=BP&region=usa&culture=en-US"
    .Visible = True
    End With

    Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Set allRowOfData = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper").getElementsByClassName("headerwrap").getElementsByClassName("r_bodywrap").getElementById("keystuts").getElementById("financeWrap").getElementByClassName("co15").getElementById("financials").getElementsByClassName("r_table1 text2").getElementsByClassName("hr").getElementsByClassName("row_1b1")

    Dim myValue As String: myValue = allRowOfData.Cells(0).innerHTML

    appIE.Quit
    Set appIE = Nothing
    Range("A1").Value = myValue
    End Sub
```

Yes I know it looks ridiculous. The runtime error I get is 438. I think its because I have no idea how websites are structured so I tried to do what I though was logical and go through each element from top to where I want to be. If you open the website the value I'm trying to get is revenue for the earliest year or any of them as an example.. if anyone can help please!!

So the code I'm trying isolate looks like this:

```
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th class="row_lbl" id="i0" scope="row">...</th>
    <td align="right" headers="Y0 i0">270,602</td>
```

The value I want is 270,602. Note that the class name is not unique but the id is. I've tried just isolating this. That link works for me but if you go Morningstar.com, search BP plc (LSE) and click on key ratios you'll see the page. I've tried isolating by just id but can't seem to get that working. Is there a way in vba to view your variables like a variable table that's in matlab?